# Como faço uma busca no banco de dados por meio de uma String em uma ApiRest?

Tags: java, web-service, jpa, spring-boot

Olá, turma!

Estou estudando desenvolvimento de ApiRest com Spring Boot. Más estou enfrentando problema quando vou fazer uma consulta por meio de String. Por meio do id funciona normalmente, más quando eu adiciono o método de busca por String  é exibido uma mensagem de erro ao subir a aplicação

"Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-07-11 09:53:28.132 ERROR 11188 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'produtoResource': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'produtoRepository'... "

Na classe repository eu tenho esse método:

```
Produto findByCb(String cb);
```

e na classe resource eu chamo ele assim:

```
@GetMapping("/produto/{cb}")
@ApiOperation(value = "Lista um dado salvo no banco de dados apartir do código de barras")
public Produto listaProdutoUnicoCb(@PathVariable(value = "cb") String cb) {
    return produtoRepository.findByCb(cb);
}
```

Eu não estou entendo esse problema, quando eu removo o método de consulta por String das classes repository e resource funciona normalmente a aplicação.

Lembrando que o método de busca por id segue a mesma implementação e funciona normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema com a ajuda desse post https://www.guj.com.br/t/erro-ao-iniciar-projeto-com-spring-boot/403288/3, Caso alguém tenha o mesmo problema!